# posting to a yammer group is throwing "Access is denied"

Tags: javascript, api, yammer

Below is the code that I am using to post to a yammer group.

```
    var testMessage = {
        body: "hello",
        group_id: 123456
    }

    var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(testMessage);

    accToken = responseObject.access_token.token;
    var accAuthHead = 'Bearer ' + accToken;

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json",
        type: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': accAuthHead.toString(),
        },
        data: testMessage,

        success: function (data) {
            alert("ajax post success.");
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("There was an error with the request." + textStatus + XMLHttpRequest.toString());
        }
    });
```

"Error : Access is denied" is thrown in the error function. Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong here.